# javascript как закрыть предыдущий div

Tags: javascript

Есть меню ! див появляется и закрывается но мне нужно что бы ПРИ КЛИКЕ ПРЕДЫДУЩИЙ ДИВ ЗАКРЫВАЛСЯ!

```
function divBlock(gett){
    if(gett.style.display == "block"){
        gett.style.display = "none";
    }else{
        gett.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

**Обновление**

```
<?php   
    function CategTableQuery(){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `catgName`");
        $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `catg`");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

                $r=mysql_fetch_array($q);
            ?>
            <div onclick="divBlock(blockCatg_<?php echo $r["id"];?>);" class="b1">
                           <p id="PcatgName" class="bl"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }

    function blockCatg($nameCatg,$num){

        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `catg` WHERE ctg='$nameCatg'");
        echo'<ul id="blockCatg_'.$num.'" class="b2" style="display:none;">';
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

            ?>
            <li id="catg_<?php echo $row["id"];?>" class="CatgStyle" >
               <a href="index.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" id="PcatgName" ><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
        echo'</ul>';
    }
    ?>
    <div id="search">
    <?php
    CategTableQuery();

     blockCatg(cw,1);
    blockCatg(ndj,2);
    blockCatg(car,3);
    blockCatg(job,4);
    blockCatg(anim,5);
    blockCatg(hom,6);
    blockCatg(elec,7);
    blockCatg(bis,8);
    blockCatg(mod,9);
    blockCatg(hob,10);
    blockCatg(exc,11);
    blockCatg(giv,12);
    ?></div><?php
    ?>

<script>
   /* var id_menu = new Array('blockCatg_1','blockCatg_2','blockCatg_3,blockCatg_4','blockCatg_5','blockCatg_6,blockCatg_7','blockCatg_8','blockCatg_9,blockCatg_10','blockCatg_11','blockCatg_12');
startList = function allclose() {
    for (i=0; i < id_menu.length; i++){
        document.getElementById(id_menu[i]).style.display = "none";
    }
}
    */


    function divBlock(gett){


        /*
         for (i=0; i < gett.length; i++){
        if (id != gett[i]){
            document.getElementById(id_menu[i]).style.display = "none";
        }
    }*/

          // var blockCatg = document.getElementById("blockCatg");
            gett.previousElementSibling.style.display = "none";
            if(gett.style.display == "block"){
                gett.style.display = "none";
            }else{
                gett.style.display = "block";
            }




    }


</script>
```

Comment: "див закрывается", кто-нибудь понял о чём это?

Comment: как я понял необходим аккордион

Comment: Ну что не понятного - диван раздвигается, утром собирается.

Comment: @Novichek Можете конкретней вопрос сформулировать? В чём Вы видите сложность решения?

Comment: друзья вот здесь ссылка где я тестю

Comment: http://evrekhgk.bget.ru/

Answer (score 2):

Мои телепатические способности подсказывают, что возможно тебе нужно просто назначить дивам какой-то один класс, и при клике в меню сначала закрывать все дивы с этим классом, а потом открывать нужный.

Подробнее без кода я не отвечу.

Answer (score 1):

если необходимый для закрытия div на том же уровне то может быть вы хотели сделать:

```
gett.previousElementSibling.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: function divBlock(gett){
        
        
        /*
         for (i=0; i < gett.length; i++){
  if (id != gett[i]){
   document.getElementById(id_menu[i]).style.display = "none";
  }
 }*/
       
          // var blockCatg = document.getElementById("blockCatg");
            gett.previousElementSibling.style.display = "none";
            if(gett.style.display == "block"){
                gett.style.display = "none";
            }else{
                gett.style.display = "block";
            }
        
   
    
        
    }

Comment: не работает  (((

Comment: я думаю проблема в том что ваш вопрос сформулирован не слишком точно. Опишите немного подробнее что вы хотите сделать, предметно покажите что у вас есть (разметку блоков например), и что именно не работает.